# Java: Как хендлить нажатия клавиш конкретного процесса?

Tags: java, ubuntu, процесс

Хочу написать небольшое приложение, с помощью которого я смогу переводить выделенный текст в PDF viewer.

**Используемая ОС:** Ubuntu 16.04.

Как я это вижу:

1. Доставать данные с буфера
2. Используя какой-нибудь апи переводчика, переводить и как-нибудь рендерить результат

**Вопрос такой:** Как мне отслеживать нажатие клавиш Ctrl + C конкретного процесса с помощью джавы? Ну, т.е., переводить только то (брать данные из буфера), что я копировал в PDF viewer'e?